# Is there an XML literal add-in for C# which can convert an XML literal to a C# object?

Tags: c#

Is there an XML literal add-in for C# which can convert an XML literal to a C# object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was just released as part of the [WCF Rest Starter Kit Preview 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24644).  It's called [Paste XML as Type](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03/16/wcf-rest-starter-kit-paste-xml-as-types.aspx).